# Is there a music-theoretical language for directly expressing voice leading?

Tags: theory, analysis, voice-leading, roman-numerals

**The question**

Does music theory provide a language for directly expressing voice leading? Roman numeral analysis (RNA) encapsulates voice-leading expectations, but these are built in by implication (indirectly) to what is a harmonic (vertical) language. Is there a more directly melodic (horizontal) language?

---

**The origin of the question**

In Bach's setting of the chorale "Ach Gott, vom Himmel sieh' darein" (BWV 2) ([IMSLP: chorale #3](https://imslp.org/wiki/371_Vierstimmige_Choralges%C3%A4nge_(Bach%2C_Johann_Sebastian))) ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpK3MSud6fk)), the final phrase is harmonically complex, but voice-leadingly simple(r). A harmonic (Roman numeral) analysis doesn't convincingly capture (IMO) what's actually happening compositionally.

Does "music theory" provide an analytical language for voice leading outside of the voice-leading expectations built into RNA? That is, is there a way to express voice leading directly?

If yes, a demonstration of how that language would be applied in this situation would be very helpful. Here is the score of the phrase in question. (Note: The preceding phrase cadences in A minor.)

[image: Choral #3, mm. 8–10]

---

**Other questions of interest**

- [Geometric Voice Leading Presentation](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/75883/70803)
- [Applying harmonic voice leading rules to non-homophonic music](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/89593/70803)

Comment: Interesting question! Can you clarify what such a language might say or do that our current system(s) don't already provide?

Comment: @Richard I've been wondering that myself, since the current language really did develop out of a desire to express voice-leading relationships between different parts — first intervalically *a la* Fux, and later, chordally with RNA. As a starting point, though, one thing that strikes me about the Bach excerpt is how, in the alto, F natural is used to place us in C major (in my analysis), but then F#-G# is used to run us toward A — but the note A rather than the key of A. This can be explained harmonically, but the explanation is, IMO, overly complex and even misleading.

Comment: @Richard What is particularly problematic in this specific chorale, is that it's considered to be in E minor — a combination of the key signature and the final (E major) chord, but the melody is B phrygian, and I hear the harmonization as being in A minor, ending on the V chord (or, at best, in E, but weakly).

Comment: @Richard  Thus it seems like it would be more accurate to toss away the harmonic analysis — which wants things to be interpreted relative to a single "home" key, and also wants pieces to end on a `I` chord (or, if not `I`, then a chord with a clear functional purpose — say, a transition to the next movement).

Comment: Looking at the score I would say that it's indeed in Am and the opening chord is the V. The first phrase clearly ends on a I that is Am. The phrase you quote is completely in Am and the only "problem" is that chord with the Bb, but we all know how much Bach likes his "tritone substitution". (Sorry, dunno what that's called in baroque harmony theory.) And I guess if he'd made it a B it would have been parallel fourths with the soprano.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout The Bb is because the chord is the viio7 of the following D major chord (C#-E-G-Bb. The E on beat 3 is an accented passing tone). The "problem" is that by analyzing the chorale in A minor, then it ends on the V chord, which, in this instance, leads to an unsatisfying RNA and flies in the face of the key signature. Anyway, the harmonic analysis is not in question (here); the issue is whether there's a formal language to directly describe voice leading.

Comment: I can't help but think that the language provided by music theory for directly expressing voice leading is called "staff notation."  It's not much of an analytical tool, however.

Comment: @Aaron The chorale is in fact in A minor (easily seen as each cadence is clearly A minor). It is common practice in german baroque notation to notate music in minor keys with doric key. This can be well seen in the same collection, number 8: The chorale is obviously in F minor, but it only features three bs, as would be expected from C minor.

Comment: @Lazy the _chorale_ is in Phrygian, transposed up a fifth so the final is B.  Whether the _harmonization_ is A minor or something else is another question.  As far as I can tell there is little to no consensus on a theoretical framework for harmonizations like this one.

Comment: @Lazy So your analysis is that the chorale ends on the V chord? And why, then, then E minor key signature? But also, not the point of the question. The question is whether there's an analytical language for describing voice leading.

Comment: @Aaron Which is the reason why I’m posting this as comment. As already said in my comment it was common practice in german baroque notation to notate minor in doric notation, thus with one step towards the sharp side. For A minor this means we get a single sharp, which is what you interpret as E minor.

Comment: @phoog I think you’re confusing *chorale* and *cantus firmus* here.

Comment: @Lazy indeed I am not.  _Chorale_ denotes the melody, whether or not it is harmonized.

Answer (score 2):

RNA will tell us unambiguously what the chord roots are.

RNA will tell us almost unambiguously what the bass line is through the figured bass inversion symbols. It won't tell us octave or anything about non-chord tones, so the line is at most a *sketch* of the bass.

The example from Bach in RNA is `Am: i | V6/3 i iv6/3 viio7/IV | IV viio7/V V |` which as a sketch bass line, without the non-chord tones and moving smallest distances, is...

[image]

I think it's possible to use standard theory terms to give a *sketch* of a soprano line, at least in some cases. You could say something like: harmonize the passage in *conjunct, contrary motion.* With the exception of the first beat of the second bar, that would give us...

[image]

...which isn't too far off of the actual line.

But, *harmonize the passage in conjunct, contrary motion* could also give us...

[image]

...which isn't like the original soprano. The pitches are different, but the contour is similar. Then again, the bass line, derived *only from the RNA* isn't all that accurately representing the original.

So, you could use standard terminology:

- line type: conjunct/disjunct
- relative motion: similar, contrary, oblique
- direction: ascending/descending

...to describe how the harmonizing soprano moves.

But that will get cumbersome quickly. Why not just annotate the Roman numeral root with one more symbol, the principle soprano tone..?

```
   ^1  |^5    ^3  ^4     ^5        | ^4  ^3       ^2 |
Am: i  | V6/3  i   iv6/3  viio7/IV |  IV  viio7/V  V |
```

...that isn't too much extra writing and it's fairly unambiguous.

That's more or less how Robert Gjerdingen expresses his voice leading schemata in *Music in the Galant Style*, except he doesn't use RNA for the bass, he just writes the scale degree number for both the soprano and the bass.

Comment: One problem with trying to define "well-formed" melodies (analogously to logical Well-Formed-Formulas) is that almost any irregularity can be made regular (or at least musical) by repetition.

Comment: I'm not saying anything about "well-formed", only that you can give short hand for a harmonizing line, well-formed or not.